# With Rails 6.2 how do I detect if I've passed an empty array into my factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-6

I’m using Rails 6.2. I have a user factory (FactoryBot 6.2) that I set up like so

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    …
    after(:build) do |user, vars|
        …
      if vars.addresses.nil?
        user.addresses = build_list(:address, 1, user: user)
      end
    end
```

My user model has

```
has_many :addresses
```

And my address model has

```
belongs_to :user
```

The problem with all of the above is that these calls behave the same way

```
create(:user, addresses: [])
```

And

```
create(:user)
```

In the first case, I want an empty array to be assigned to the user object.  In the second case, I would like the addresses auto-created using my address factory.  How do I distinguish between passing in an empty array and not passing in anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use transients for this sort of thing to make it clear what I'm trying to do.

So something like:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    transient do
      with_addresses { true }
    end

    ...

    after(:build) do |user, vars|
      if vars.with_addresses == true
        user.addresses = build_list(:address, 1, user: user)
      elsif vars.with_addresses
        user.addresses = vars.with_addresses
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then:

```
create(:user) # Builds one address for the user
create(:user, with_addresses: []) # Starts with no addresses
create(:user, with_addresses: [a1, a2]) # Starts with two addresses
```

And you could make it a little smarter and more flexible so that you could say things like:

```
create(:user, with_addresses: 0) # To create with none
create(:user, with_addresses: 6) # To get 6 from your address factory
```

You'd just need a couple small tweaks to the `after(:build)` block.